# What is wrong with for loop code?

Tags: r

I have to create a function ans(k) that can return a vector with every Fibonacci number less than or equal to k. I know basics of loops but i am not able to understand the logic. Can someone please explain with a bit description how can i solve the above problem. What i tried is:

i created a vector first

```
k<-c(1, 1)
```

Then as usual for creating function i used:

```
ans <- function(k) {
+ for(i in k){
```

then re modified the k vector as:

```
k=c(k, k[i-1] + k[i-2])
}
return(k)
}
```

where I am going wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ans <- function(n) {
  k<-c(1, 1)
  for(i in 3:n){
    k=c(k,k[i-1]+k[i-2])
  }
  return(k)
}

ans(5)
```

1. You cannot use twice `k` as and index and as a storage of your fibonnaci series!
2. Your series start at 3, because the two first ones are 1 and 1
3. On the other hand, it is better to keep `k` inside `ans` function because of scope and clarity!